Emergency mode pop os
Вчера я обновлял систему, но при попытке обновления она выдала ошибку. Я не придал этому значения, так как такое было раньше и ничего не ломалось. Сегодня же при попытке включения компьютер выдаёт такую ошибку:
Система пишет "You are in emergency mode". Также говорит что-то про invalid name и type_id bits_offset.
Я пока ничего не предпринимал, так как я ещё новичок в использовании линукса и боюсь что-то сломать. Что можно сделать в такой ситуации?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Загружать live-систему с диска/флешки, заходить в chroot и доустанавливать прерванные обновления
